# Custom node names with XML serialization (.NET)

Tags: .net, xml, xml-serialization

I have the following code:

```
public class Foo {}

static class Program {
    [XmlElement("foo")] // Ignored :(
    static public List<Foo> MyFoos { get; private set; }

    public static void Main() {
        MyFoos.Add(new Foo());
        MyFoos.Add(new Foo());

        XmlSerializer configSerializer = 
            new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Foo>), new XmlRootAttribute("foos"));
        using (TextWriter w = new StreamWriter("test.xml"))
        {
            s.Serialize(w, MyFoos);
        }
    }
}
```

Which produces the following XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<foos xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Foo />
  <Foo />
</foos>
```

What I would really like to have is the `Foo` elements labeled as `foo`, instead... I realise this is mostly cosmetic, but it fits with what is generally considered normal in XML.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It should work if you set the element name directly ...

```
   [XmlElement( ElementName = "foo" )]
```

See example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute.aspx).  Is the point that it has to be static?  If so, this is not helpful, but this works fine (added the round trip per comment) ...

```
namespace TestSerial
{
    public class Foo
    {
        public int Value
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
    public class SerializeMe
    {
        private List<Foo> _foos = new List<Foo>();
        public SerializeMe()
        {
        }

        [XmlElement("foo")]
        public List<Foo> MyFoos { get { return _foos; } }

    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var fs = new SerializeMe();
            fs.MyFoos.Add(new Foo() { Value = 1 });
            fs.MyFoos.Add(new Foo() { Value = 2 });

            var s = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SerializeMe), new XmlRootAttribute("foos"));
            using (var w = new StreamWriter(@"c:\temp\test.xml"))
            {
                s.Serialize(w, fs);
            }

            using (var r = new StreamReader(@"c:\temp\test.xml"))
            {
                var o = s.Deserialize(r);
                var fs2 = (SerializeMe)o;

                fs2.MyFoos.Select(f => f.Value).ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT: (Matthew, OP)**

My final solution, which I consider a refinement of the above was:

```
public class Foo {}

[XmlRoot("foos")]
public class FooList 
{
    public FooList() { Foos = new List<Foo>(); }
    [XmlElement("foo")]
    public List<Foo> Foos { get; set; }
}

static class Program 
{
    static private FooList _foos = new FooList();
    static public List<Foo> MyFoos { get { return _foos; } }

    public static void Main() 
    {
        MyFoos.Add(new Foo());
        MyFoos.Add(new Foo());

        XmlSerializer configSerializer = 
            new XmlSerializer(typeof(FooList));

        using (TextReader r = new StreamReader("test.xml"))
        {
            _foos = (FooList)configSerializer.Deserialize(r);
        }

        using (TextWriter w = new StreamWriter("test.xml"))
        {
            configSerializer.Serialize(w, _foos);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: XmlElementAttribute isn't allowed on class definitions: Attribute 'XmlElement' is not valid on this declaration type. It is only valid on 'property, indexer, field, param, return' declarations.

Comment: It's a static property and will always be ignored.

Comment: Ah!  Bitten by the toy example I guess.

Comment: Something I'd like to avoid... but does it work properly with deserialising it again too? (I'm slightly worried about the lack of a setter on the property, but I'm new to this)

Comment: I'm going to edit this and add my final solution, since I find it a bit cleaner than this one, but it is based heavily on this one, so it should be accepted.